# Counting symbols in drawings

Tags: images

We have scanned plans of buildings and we need to count how many of particular symbols (e.g. windows, doors...) are in this image. We are counting them manually now.

Is there any way or software to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There may be software that can do this...

However, if you need to be exact, you will need to double check it yourself.  When you scan a paper document to digital formats there can, and will be errors.  Even the best optical character recognition (OCR) programs make errors and still have to be checked by a human.  Problems like creases in the paper, a hair on the scanner, a paper that doesnt sit flat, colors that dont scan well, paper not aligned properly, etc can cause the digital output to be flawed.

If you need your counts to be accurate, you will have to still check them yourself.  Recreating the plans in a digital format is the only way to be accurate.